# How to get a length of the array in Denodo?

Tags: denodo

I have a column in the Denodo view with the type ARRAY. How can I get the length of this array? Standard sql `ARRAY_LENGTH` function is not working.

Comment: Review:Can you add a sample SQL statement and its output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
COUNT((<ARRAY_FIELD>).value)
```

Notice that you can not use COUNT() over the aggregate function LIST() directly.